# How events work in Yii2

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I have been trying to learn how event works in Yii from the [Yii Guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-concept-events.html). I have found there are most important things: `Event Handlers`, `Attaching Event Handlers` and `Triggering Events`. I have read entire the article properly. But I don't understand how to implement these three things properly. How to see the effect of it's implementation. I have extended `component` class as:

```
namespace app\components;

use yii\base\Component;
use yii\base\Event;
use yii\web\View;

class Foo extends Component{

   const EVENT_HELLO = 'hello';

   public function bar()
   {
      $this->trigger(self::EVENT_HELLO);
   }

}
```

I do not understand what is the next part to do. Where I should write the [Attaching Event Handlers](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-concept-events.html#attaching-event-handlers). Can you help me someone, at least I can see a simple output using event.

Comment: Here is detail answer about events: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28575636/how-to-use-events-in-yii2/28586567#28586567

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You may create `init()` method in model:

```
public function init()
    {
        $this->on(Event::ACTION_ADD, ['app\models\Event', 'sendInLog']);
        $this->on(Event::ACTION_DELETE, ['app\models\Event', 'sendInLog']);
        $this->on(Event::ACTION_UPDATE, ['app\models\Event', 'sendInLog']);
    }
```

In initialize events in second parameter you may use current model or set other model. If you want use current model set like that:

```
[$this, 'sendInLog']
```

`sendInLog` it is method in model. In method `sendInLog` one parameter it is `$event`. This is object `\yii\base\Event`. In property `$event->name` - it is event name. In property `$event->sender` - it is model class from trigger event.

In my class `app\models\Event` like that:

```
namespace app\models;

class Event extends Component
{
    const ACTION_ADD = 1;
    const ACTION_DELETE = 2;
    const ACTION_UPDATE = 3;

    const TYPE_PROJECT = 10;
    const TYPE_BIDS = 20;
    const TYPE_BIDS_DATA = 30;

    /**
     * @param $event
     */
    public static function sendInLog($event)
    {
        /** @var \yii\base\Event $event */
        /** @var ActiveRecord $event->sender */
        $userId = Yii::$app->user->id;
        $model = new Logs([
            'type' => $event->sender->getType(),
            'action' => $event->name,
            'id_user' => $userId,
            'old_data' => Json::encode($event->sender->attributes),
            'new_data' => Json::encode($event->sender->oldAttributes),
        ]);
        $model->save();
    }
}
```

Run trigger like that:

```
public function afterDelete()
    {
        $this->trigger(Event::ACTION_DELETE);
        parent::afterDelete();
    }
```

Or

```
public function actionView()
    {
        $this->trigger(Event::ACTION_VIEW);
        $this->render(...);
    }
```

EDIT:

For example. If you want run trigger after delete, insert, update. You  may use trigger in `afterDelete`, `afterSave` in model. If you want run trigger in controller run trigger like that:

```
public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model = new Bids();
        $model->id_project = Yii::$app->request->get('projectId');
        $fieldsDefaults = BidsFieldsDefaults::find()->orderBy(['order' => SORT_ASC])->all();

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
            $model->trigger(Event::ACTION_ADD);
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
        } else {
            return $this->render('create', [
                'model' => $model,
                'fieldsDefaults' => $fieldsDefaults
            ]);
        }
    }
```

I show you two different ways to run trigger. Which one to use is up to you :)

Comment: Thanks it's a nice example, let me check it and try :)

Comment: Can you tell me please about `afterDelete()` and `actionView()`. They will be in the model?

Comment: just one thing, can you tell me about `$model = new Logs` please. Because I am getting an error, `app\models\Logs`.

Comment: I got the concept now. So far I understand Logs is `model`. After event trigger, a log data will be stored in database. I have created a `Logs` model but when I trigger event `ACTION_ADD`, `\yii\base\Event::sendInLog` does not save the data in db.

Comment: You wrong is `\yii\base\Event`. I create new class `app\models\Event` (he code in my answer). This class a example how work with trigger.

Comment: Sorry mentioned wrong in the above comment. I wrote class in `app\models\Event`. However, it works fine here when I want to echo any text. But I can't save logs data in database while trigger. Anyway, I want to give you a lot of thanks for your big help.

Comment: I saw event handler can be attach in component section of config file using the syntex `'on eventName' => $eventHandler,`. Can I do it for this example?