# Yii2: How to use events to set flash messages when new records get created in MySQL (event listeners)

Tags: php, mysql, yii2, flash-message

How do I notify user on dashboard(index.php) as soon as new records get created in database or any changes made in database

Iknow I need to query like

```
CREATE TRIGGER notifyMe

    ON table1
    AFTER INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE 
    AS
       EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
            @profile_name = 'DB AutoMailer',
            @recipients = 'user@example.com',
            @body = 'The DB has changed',
            @subject = 'DB Change';
    GO
```

but dont know how to do it by using Yii2 Events

In controller:

```
  Yii::$app->session->setFlash('success', "Your message to display");
```

In view

```
<?php if (Yii::$app->session->hasFlash('success')): ?>
  <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissable">
  <button aria-hidden="true" data-dismiss="alert" class="close" type="button">×</button>
  <h4><i class="icon fa fa-check"></i>Saved!</h4>
  <?= Yii::$app->session->getFlash('success') ?>
  </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: I've explained `yii2 events` here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28575636/how-to-use-events-in-yii2/28586567#28586567. I think it'll help you to design the solution.

Comment: nice!! any tips to build event listeners?

Comment: Everything about events and event handlers are explained in detailed in the yii2 guide.Please refer this link http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-concept-events.html

Comment: i need, how will yii detect that database has been changed

Comment: @Saurabh.If yii code has done changes to your db,then surely you can trigger events based on the change.